# How do you clear text from a table cell on iOS with xamarin.UITest?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitest, xamarin.uitest

I have been trying to use:

```
ClearText(c => c.Class("MyCell").Index(0));
```

The output says:

```
 "Clearing text in element
  Using element matching Class("MyCell").Index(0)."
```

But the text stays put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to target the "UITextField" rather than "MyCell"

Comment: Can you please share your repl tree?

Comment: Perhaps you could try .Marked("MyCell") rather than .class()